# Error in Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda

I am using tensorflow object ditection API.i cant find any solution for this.please help me.

my code is

```
MODEL_NAME = 'inference_graph'
PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
PATH_TO_LABELS = 'training/labelmap.pbtxt'

detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
serialized_graph = fid.read()
od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

Error shown

```
<ipython-input-10-d55b98fd5a78> in <module>
  3   od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  4   with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
   ----> 5     serialized_graph = fid.read()
  6     od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
  7     tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py in 
 read(self, n)
123       string if in string (regular) mode.
124     """
--> 125     self._preread_check()
126     with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:
127       if n == -1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py in 
_preread_check(self)
 83       with errors.raise_exception_on_not_ok_status() as status:
 84         self._read_buf = pywrap_tensorflow.CreateBufferedInputStream(
 ---> 85             compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
 86 
 87   def _prewrite_check(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py 
in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
526             None, None,
527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it 
stays alive
530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback 
due to

NotFoundError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: 
inference_graph/frozen_inference_graph.pb : The system cannot find the 
path specified.
; No such process
```

the file directory exist in inference_graph/frozen_inference_graph.pb but why this error is occuring?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be divided into two parts. The first part will be to detect the number plate in the image and second part will be to recognize the characters on the number plate. You can easily find dataset for both cases online on data repos like Kaggle or UCI repo. The CNN model will traverse over the image of the car till it finds the number plate. Once the number plate is found, a model will traverse over the plate to read characters.

Stackoverflow is not the right place for this question as we cannot give you any model architecture without knowing your dataset so look at online resources like [this](https://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/).